# How to search data from oracle database which contains single quote

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

`my_table` contains three columns: `name`, `address1`, and `address2`.

I want to find all records which contains single quotes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to escape the single quotes in the expressions by doubling them, e.g.:

```
select * from my_table
where name like '%''%'
or address1 like '%''%'
or address2 like '%''%';
```

Answer (score 2):

... where name || address1 || address2 like '%''%';